# How to resize disk of virtual machine based on the azure monitor alert

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I have created azure monitor alert based on Log Analytics Workspace resource using kusto query and I am successfully getting low disk space alert email. Now instead of email i want to resize my disk automatically based on the azure monitor alert. So can someone help on this is it possible using powershell or any other thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to resize the disk automatically based on the alerts. We need to do it manually.

Comment: Can we use Azure function from Action Type?

Comment: There is no option from azure functions as well.